# Find: $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{2n}\left(1-\left(f ^{\circ n}(x)\right)\right)\right)$

Tags: limits, function-and-relation-composition

Let $$f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\;\;\mbox{defined by}\;\;\; f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{2}}$$

Find:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{2n}\left(1-\left(\overbrace {f \circ f \circ f \cdot\cdot\cdot \circ f}^{n}(x)\right)\right)\right)$$

---

I mainly need help with simplifying the composite function. I'll try to take it on from there. Any (substantial) hints or solutions will be greatly and sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the substitution $x = \cos \theta$. Then $f(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos \theta}{2}} = \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2}$. Hence, $f^{(n)}(x) = \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2^n}$.

So, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}2^{2n}(1-f^{(n)}(x)) = \lim_{n \to \infty}2^{2n}\left(1-\cos \dfrac{\theta}{2^n}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}2^{2n}\left(\dfrac{\theta^2}{2 \cdot 2^{2n}}+O\left(\dfrac{1}{2^{4n}}\right)\right) = \dfrac{\theta^2}{2}$ $= \dfrac{1}{2}(\arccos x)^2$.

Taking the limit as $x \to 0$ should be easy.

Comment: Slick. Could you elaborate on how you solved the last limit involving the Big O notation?

Comment: @Kugelblitz, basically $\frac{1}{2^{4n}} \to 0$

Comment: Then it makes sense. Could you also explain how you decomposed the penultimate limit into the limit involving the O notation?

Comment: @Kugelblitz That's just Taylor expansion of cosine.

Comment: The Taylor series for $\cos x$ about $x = 0$ is $\cos x = 1-\tfrac{1}{2}x^2+\tfrac{1}{24}x^4 - \cdots$. As $n \to \infty$, $\frac{\theta}{2^n} \to 0$, so the Taylor series gives us $\cos \frac{\theta}{2^n} = 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2 \cdot 2^{2n}} + \frac{\theta^4}{24 \cdot 2^{4n}} - \cdots$. Hence, $2^{2n}(1-\cos\frac{\theta}{2^{2n}}) = \frac{\theta^2}{2} - \frac{\theta^4}{24 \cdot 2^{2n}} + \cdots$. As $n \to \infty$, all the higher order terms tend to $0$, so we are left with $\tfrac{\theta^2}{2}$.

Comment: @Nameless No, it's that $\frac{2^{2n}}{2^{4n}}\to 0$. You have to have the second factor.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yes I forgot the $2^{2n}$ was outside. He was asking about "big oh" and i just looked at the "O".